# How to create an Exchange Account in Android Emulator using 4.3

Tags: android

I have to add an Exchange Account in Android Emulator to work with GCM & Calendar API. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-a-google-account-in-the-emulator/) for creating an account, but whenever I am trying to set an account I get the following error:

```
  Couldn't open Connection to Server
```

*By using any other APIs, I am getting* : **`the server requires security features your phone does not support`** for *an example* in **Android APIs 4.0**

Here are some things I've noticed:

- As you can see below in my screen shot, there is one more field for `PORT - 443` getting by default.

**AVD Screen Shot:**

[image]

**Account Setup Couldn't Finish Screen Shot:**

[image]

---

If I do this:

[image]

I get this error message:

[image]

I am using same credentials which I always use to login to my GMAIL Account, but in process of creating Exchange Account in Emulator I am getting `Incorrect UserName or Password`

Please see below screen shot:

[image]

in above image i have used my google account username

```
    (i.e: androidsmartappdeveloper@googlemail.com)
```

and has entered correct password but getting the error below:

[image]

I have tried by using 6 different email IDs and have had friends try, but we all getting same dialog `Couldn't Finish`

How can I resolve this problem?

Earlier I was using an AVD and by using that AVD I was able to work with GCM, Calendar and more. I deleted that AVD and now whenever I am trying to create AVD using lower version I get `the server requires security features your phone does not support`

Comment: Why are you using google api 18 and Nexus one avd. GCM work with Google API 8 with HVGA slider

Comment: @Sneha: have you been able to fix this? Any workaround? I am facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Settings->Accounts->Add account->Corporate

2.Enter your email address and password

3.Domain\username: (netbios domain name\your username)

4.Password: (your password)

5.Server = (possibly mail.company.com, owa,comapny.com or remote.company.com)

6.Leave use SSL checked and Accept all SSL unchecked

7.Leave port as 443

8.Next -> "Remote security administration" press ok.

9.Select the settings you want (leave as default if you like)

Comment: first check my screen shots

Comment: Not sure that will work for the Emulator. Did you noticed the "Mobile Device ID"? Is that unique? ask your friends.

Comment: As i have written trying to create an Exchange account in Emulator

Answer (score 0):

Create avd with following configurations

[image]

Select Google (
**Note:** If you select **Corporate** to add gmail account than it is not possible )

[image]

Enter Username & password

[image]

Comment: kirit are you not getting : "the server requires security features your phone does not support"

Comment: why it is not possible to create a Corporate Account, earlier i had created

Comment: If you select Corporate to add gmail account than it is not possible

Comment: not useful, for last 15 mins emulator running but not launching home screen, any-ways i don't need any temporary solution, bcoz habit to face reality, and today's reality is not able to create a Corporate Account, forget the past

Comment: You can try yahoo or other account using Corporate option

Comment: I told earlier that you can not add google account using Corporate Option. I never success on configuring  corporate account for gmail. It is advice to use Google option for configuring gmail account

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34695/discussion-between-kirit-and-sneha)

Comment: The first option "Corporate account" established an MS Exchange compatible connection to the Google server. As Google dropped support for this protocol, it is not useable anymore. (see here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2716936?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Are you a paid gmail account user? Because as per this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2716936?hl=en)

> Starting January 30, 2013, users, other than paid Google Apps users, won't be able to set up new devices using Google Sync.

So the tutorial you followed to create exchange account won't work. As of now I couldn't find any other solution provided by google for this functionality.